# Pandas: How to split the title name and columns by \t one by one?

Tags: python, pandas, split

How do I split the title name and columns by `\t` one by one?

Now, the situation is that loading the txt file into pandas gives these column names:

```
Cust_id\tSex\tBMI\tChildren\tDistrict
```

I want the columns to be:

```
Cust_id Sex BMI Children District
```

Also like this one:

```
C210\tM\t22.99\t2\tManchester
```

I want the columns to be:

```
C210 M 22.99 2 Manchester
```

I tried to use the `split` function to fix them but failed:

```
df.split('\t')
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: It always pays to read the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). The `sep` parameter (see the answer by @n7d below) is the second parameter explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to define the separator when loading the file into dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_name', sep='\t')
```